# ASP.NET MVC 2 actions for the same route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Suppose I have defined route like that,

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Preview",
            "/preview/{id}/{type}",
            new { controller = "Preview", action = "Invoice", id = UrlParameter.Optional, type = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have controller with action Invoice

```
public ActionResult(int id, string type)
{
  if (type == "someType") 
  {
    // ...
  } 
  else
  {
    // ..
  }
}
```

I want to get rid of If-Else case inside the action. Is it possible to attribute action somehow, so ASP.MVC would distinguish between both, like:

Just a pseudocode tho show idea?

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("Action"), ForParameter("type", "someType")]
public ActionResult PreviewSomeType(int id) {}

[HttpGet, ActionName("Action"), ForParameter("type", "someType2")]
public ActionResult PreviewSomeType2(int id) {}
```

Is something like that possible in MVC2/3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Action method selector

What you need is an Action Method Selector that does exactly what you're describing and are used **exactly for this purpose** so that's not a kind of a workaround as it would be with a different routing definition or any other way. Custom action method selector attribute is **the solution** not a workaround.

I've written two blog posts that will get you started with action method selection in Asp.net MVC and these kind of attributes:

- [Improving Asp.net MVC maintainability and RESTful conformance](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/improving-aspnet-mvc-maintainability.html)
  this particular post shows an action method selector that removes action method code branches what you'd also like to accomplish;
- [Custom action method selector attributes in Asp.net MVC](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/using-custom-action-method-selector.html)
  explains action method selection in Asp.net MVC to understand the inner workings of it while also providing a selector that distinguishes normal vs. Ajax action methods for the same request;

Comment: Yes, I think Action Method Selector is very applicable!

Answer (score 0):

I think thats what routing is for.
Just split your single route into two:

```
context.MapRoute(null, "preview/{id}/SomeType",
        new { 
              controller = "Preview", 
              action = "Action1", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            }
    );

context.MapRoute(null, "preview/{id}/SomeOtherType",
        new { controller = "Preview", 
              action = "Action2", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            }
    );
```

Or maybe more general, use the last segment as the action name:

```
context.MapRoute(null, "preview/{id}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Preview",
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            }
    );
```

But i think, optional segments have to appear at the end. So why don't you use the default routing schema

```
controller/action/id
```

?

Comment: thanks, but I would be happy to avoid several routes definitions;

Comment: but, I would agree with 3 option - general one :) meanwhile I fould that possiblity http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.aspx