# ASP .NET MVC 3 same route for multiple actions based on criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible in ASP .NET MVC 3+ to have one same route for multiple actions based on specific state ?

For instance, on LinkedIn or some similar sites, same route `http://site-domain/home` 
is used for multiple views.

If the user is not loggedin, home page displays a welcome view, but if the user is loggedin, then user's home page where his notifications and other user specific data is displayed.

Can we use the same route url to route to different actions of different controllers depending on the user's loggedin status, or any other type of data controls ?

Note: Displaying a diffrent view in the same action is not an option since two actions have completely different logic.

Comment: Why not keep the action same and change the view based on specific state?

Comment: Because logic in both actions are totally different so it can't be handled with only changing the view

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You have a couple of options, the first one is to serve the user a view of your choosing based on some of his properties but then you have a limited control over the view model.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(){

if(User.Identity.Name == "Admin")
    return View("AdminView");
else
    return View("SomeOtherView");
}
```

Another option is to redirect the user once inside the controller method to another action as instructed in: http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/02/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-redirecting-to-another-action-and-passing-information-to-it.aspx

Of course there is always an option of rendering partial views on the page based on some user property. If you could perhaps give some more information regarding your project that would help finding a solution.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. I don't want to display another view, I want to route to another action. This is different from a redirect as well.

Comment: Then why not use return RediredtToAction("ActionName") with the action name corresponding to the appropriate action for that user?

Comment: BTW, if this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600949/asp-net-mvc-2-actions-for-the-same-route?

Comment: Thanks Smisak. Custom action method selector can be an option if same controller is to be used. Not exactly what I look for but may help